# Migrated questions are loaded in newest questions via WebSockets, but disappear after refreshing

Tags: bug, migration, web-sockets, newest-questions

I've just had the following situation on Meta Stack Overflow:

- I was on the [newest questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest) page.
- "1 new question" appeared. I clicked that, and [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/335536/3853934), which was migrated from Meta Stack Exchange, was added at the top of the question list.
- After refreshing the page, the question disappeared from the list. Now it's on the 17th page (when displaying 50 questions per page), along with other questions which was asked on August 29th.

I think that this question either shouldn't be displayed in the newest questions at all, or it should stay there after refreshing the page.